# MongoDB $elemMatch Index

Tags: optimization, mongodb, indexing

I have an mongo query that looks like the following:

```
{'schedule': {'$elemMatch': {'time': {'$gt': start, '$lte': end}}}}
```

Which searches a collection for an item whose "schedule" field (which is a list of objects) that contains an element whose "time" field is between start and end.

I am unclear as to how mongo's indexes handle this situation, and wonder what would be the best practice, if this query were going to be happening regularly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the wrong syntax, but should work. $elemMatch is used when there is more than one field in an object (esp. in an array) that you want to match. With a single field there is no need for $elemMatch.

You should be doing this:

`{"schedule.time" : { $gt: <start>, $lte: <end> }}`

It is much more clear that you are using a single field, even though it will be in multiple array elements, in this case. An index on "schedule.time" can be used for this query to make it more efficient.

Comment: Good point.  I did not think that would work, because if schedule was a list of ints instead of a list of objects and you did {'schedule': {'$gt': start, '$lte': end}}, it would match all items that have both an element > start and an element <= end, but not necessarily the same element.  I checked and your version works, and is more clear.  Thank you.

Comment: Very bizzarre behavior!  This works if an index is built on schedule.time, but not if there is not such index.

Comment: Kevin: there are some bugs related to indexed/unindexed range queries on arrays which are version dependent. If you have an example that doesn't work on the latest version please create a jira issue: http://jira.mongodb.org/